# How to write a functor over arrays and strings?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to make my code generic over strings and arrays (any indexable type really) using the following signature:

```
module type Indexable = sig
  type 'a t
  val get : int -> 'a t -> 'a
end
```

`module MyCode (I : Indexable) = struct ... end`

But of course I cannot apply my signature to strings as follows:

```
module StrMyCode = MyCode(struct
  type 'a t = string
  let get i a = a.[i]
end)
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Or perhaps a different aprroach? I know I can use arrays of characters in the worst case but I'd rather save my code from ugly casts and this is something that was on my mind before so I'd like to get a clear answer for this.

Answer (score 6):

GADT can be used with the functorized approach:

```
module type Indexable = sig
  type 'a t
  val get: int -> 'a t -> 'a
end

module MyCode(I:Indexable) = struct
 let head x = I.get 0 x
end
```

Arrays can of course be made `Indexable` trivially:

```
module IndexableArray = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array
  let get i x = x.(i)
end
```

For string, you can just use a GADT with a single constructor. Note however, that you have to put some type annotation for get in order to force the polymorphic type (otherwise, the inferred type is `int -> char t -> char`):

```
module IndexableString = struct
  type 'a t = String: string -> char t
  let of_string s = String s
  let get: type a. int -> a t -> a =
    fun i s -> match s with String s -> s.[i]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is something I made using GADTs. I'm just wrapping my head around them, so there may be something a little wrong here. But it seems to work as far as I can see (with OCaml 4):

```
type _ indexable =
    | A : 'a array -> 'a indexable
    | C : string -> char indexable

let index (type s) (x: s indexable) i : s =
    match x with
    | A a -> a.(i)
    | C s -> s.[i]

let main () =
    let x = A [| 1; 2 |] in
    let y = C "abc" in
    Printf.printf "%d\n" (index x 0);
    Printf.printf "%c\n" (index y 1)
```

If I load into the toplevel, I get this:

```
val index : 'a indexable -> int -> 'a = <fun>
val main : unit -> unit = <fun>
# main ();;
1
b
- : unit = ()
#
```

This might not be as general as what you're looking for.

Comment: Ya this is a clever solution but I'm taking the functor approach because I'd like users to able to implement their own indexables

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the element type of the indexable as a separate type, you can do something like this:

```
module type Indexable = sig
  type t
  type elt
  val get : int -> t -> elt
end

module IndexableString : Indexable = struct
  type t = string
  type elt = char
  let get i a = a.[i]
end

module MyCode (I : Indexable) = struct
  (* My code implementation *)
end

module StrMyCode = MyCode(IndexableString)
```

For arrays, you can do more or less the same:

```
module ArrayIndexable = struct
    type elt = char
    type t = char array
    let get i a = a.(i)
end
```

Now, if you wish to retain some flexibility with arrays, you may change the above into a functor:

```
module ArrayIndexable (E : sig type e end) : Indexable with type elt = E.e =
struct
    type elt = e
    type t = elt array

    let get i a = a.(i)
end
```

It is more verbose than the polymorphic version you are looking for, but it let you encode both "indexable" types uniformly.

Comment: How would implement Indexable for an array then `type t = 'a array` won't typecheck. Also even if this worked then I think I'd still lose the parametric polymorphism of the container. For example I'd have to instantiate my functor individually for `int array` and `string array`. Perhaps what I'm asking for doesn't even make sense since I'd like to keep my instantiated functors polymorphic over the the value in the container except for 1 case: string. Don't even know if what I typed even makes sense now...

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a way to do it that would let you keep the parametric polymorphism over the element type.